# JSON Post to Mysql

Tags: php, json

I have a Tuya door sensor. This calls with each activity a post office to a Json file which lies on a China server.

```
/gw.json?a=s.gw.dev.update&gwId=XXX
```

I redirected by DNS entry the domain on my Raspberrypi. Now the question is how do I build a script that ends. Json that the data saves me in MySQL?

PHP would not be a problem but a post to a json file?

thanks

Comment: Just because the URL is `/gw.json`, does not mean this is or must be an actual “JSON file”. Go read up on how to execute PHP code under different file endings than `.php`

Answer (score -1):

thank you very much. I solved the problem with an httaccess file.

AddType application/x-httpd-php .json